# date function not showing for every iteration

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently inherited a website at work. I don't really know PHP.

The below code is supposed to iterate through each post that exists on our wordpress site and post the date that it was posted.

```
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                <span class="the_date">Posted: <?php the_date() ?></span>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>                     
            </li>            
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

It isn't quite working. It does this, but for posts that land on the same day it doesn't post the date:

[image]

How do I get the date to show up for every iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date):

> **SPECIAL NOTE**: When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag [the_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time) or [get_the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date) (since [3.0](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.0)) with a [date-specific format string](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time).

Comment: The `get_the_date()` function doesn't "echo" the date, only returns it.  ["Unlike the_date() this tag will always return the date."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date).  Instead try: `<?= get_the_date('F j, Y') ?>` (which may or may not work depending on your PHP version and/or whether you have short open tags enabled) or `<?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y') ?>`

Comment: I am getting the same result for both of these: Posted: F j, Y http://i.imgur.com/g5hC1M6.png

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you using?  And have you tried it without any arguments: `<?= get_the_date() ?>`

Comment: It works without any arguments. Odd that the arguments don't work. I'm using wordpress version 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <span class="the_date">Posted: <?php echo !empty(get_the_date()) ? get_the_date() : date('d/m/Y'); ?></span>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>                     
    </li>            
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This adds a fallback to todays date if get_the_date() is not available. Also I have formatted your HTML, as h3 tags should not be allowed within anchor tags.